Firebase storage not working with flutter on windows
When I try to upload an image to firebase storage and then get the download URL of that image, it displays this error:

Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///D:/FOLDER/PROJECT_NAME/

It seems that the image is not being uploaded at all and that's why there is no URL being returned.
Here is the code relevant to the issue:
Create Product Function:
try {
  Storage().uploadImage(chosenImage!).then((downloadUrl) async {
    await Database().addProduct(
      imageUrl: downloadUrl,
    );
  });
} catch (e) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    const SnackBar(content: Text('Something went wrong.')),
  );
  print(e);
}

Image Picker Function:
XFile? image =  await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
setState(() {
  chosenImage = image;
});

Image Upload Function:
Future<String> uploadImage(XFile image) async {
  try {
    UploadTask upload = _storage.ref().putFile(File(image.path));
    return await upload.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  } catch (e) {
    return 'error';
  }
}

It also gives me the error: [firebase_storage/unknown] an unknown error occurred which is absolutely not helping in any way.
Note: I checked my storage rules. They are perfectly fine and not causing problems.

Well...the file:///D:/FOLDER/PROJECT_NAME/ doesn't point to a file in Cloud Storage. What exact line in the code you shared throws that specific error?
